# how to set visibility of div in controller (SAP UI5)

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts, sapui5

I have designed a SAP UI5 Application

I have a div which contains highcharts.

```
<html:div id="Tab2Chart" class="sapUiSmallMarginBegin sapUiSmallMarginTop" 
   style="width:45%;float:left;height:auto"></html:div>
```

Now, A button is present in View. On clicking it, above div should hide i.e. highchart should not be visible. How to achieve this. i am able to get div in controller by using-

```
 var _ID2= this.getView().byId("Tab2Chart").getId();
```

After this, suggest me solution.

Comment: Try `_ID2.setVisible(false);`

Comment: I had tried it. It throws error -
Uncaught TypeError: _ID2.setVisible is not a function

Comment: `var _ID2= this.getView().byId("Tab2Chart");
_ID2.setVisible(false);`

Comment: Thanks, It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the answer to this here:

You can always refer any items through their ids as:
this.getView().byId("idOfIntentedElement")

- Refer the view : this.getView()
- Refer element in the views by their ids : this.getView().byId("id")

```js
this.getView().byId("Tab2Chart").setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard setVisible method or jQuery hide method commented below.

```
var _ID2= this.getView().byId("Tab2Chart").getId();
this.getView().byId("Tab2Chart").setVisible(false);
// $('#'+_ID2).hide();
```